# Java: Playing a GIF once

Tags: java, swing, gif

So im a relatively new to Java and I'm currently trying to make a turn based rpg. I was able to add idle animations as JLabels and when i click the "attack" button i want the attack.gif to play once and return to the idle.gif. Any way I could set that up?

example of the code:

```
    if(source == menu.attack) {
        //disabling the attack button for the duration of the animation
        menu.attack.setEnabled(false);

        //setting the idle animation to invisible
        menu.idle.setVisible(false);
        //setting the attack animation to visible
        menu.attack.setVisible(true);


        player.attack(enemy, menu);
        update(player, enemy, menu);
        }
```

Comment: one easy way (seems to me:) use two images. 1 gif, and 1 jpg. when action (hide jpg & show gif) after timeout of few seconds hide gif & show jpg) but setting it as "one and only one movement" ..

Comment: can't you catch an event when the animation end?

Comment: If you know the duration of the animation, you could use that to return to the idle.gif after a timeout.

Comment: @Stultuske how can i set that up? I tried it with .sleep methods but it just freezed the whole gui for the time i set up.

Comment: You should never "sleep" the EDT thread in Swing. A solution, might be "stance is changed event" -> Set the JLabel with the GIF content, wait for "duration of GIF", -> Set the Jlabel to another Icon.

Comment: depending on how your game works, you could also base it on frames rather than time, which can vary. Basically: split your gif in several images, display them in order, finally display the iddle image.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul, but then for something else with an animation like that he would have to hard-code the duration as well, and come back to it each time something changes.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov true. But there may be relatively few of them, with infrequent changes, so much more might just be overkill. Otherwise a different more media-orientated view technology (such as JavaFX instead of Swing) could be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), to control the animation state;

A suggestion:

```
public void doAttackAnimation(){
   new Thread(()-> {
         setIcon("Your Attack Animation");
         sleep(durationOfAnimation);
         setIcon("default Animation");
      }).start();
}
```

Comment: This worked really well! Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: (1-) Don't use a Thread for this. Swing component should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread. So you should 1) set the icon. 2) start a Swing Timer 3) when the Timer fires you change the icon. Or, if you really want to use the Thread, then all the updates to the label need to be wrapped in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on this topic. You could even use a `SwingWorker` as described in the tutorial.